# I use lots of container widget. am I doing right?

Tags: flutter

I am new at flutter. In my app for positioning widgets i use container. All my widgets in container and in container I use height, width with mediaquery for positioning. I tried to use expanded instead of container but i couldn't use it. I am little obsessed with pixels and positioning. Am i doing right? Using 20-25 containers in one page is normal thing?

Comment: I can guess, from the number of Containers you are using, you are wrapping everything inside container. No everything goes inside container(You have to be smart about using it). If you can share your code, people can suggest you the best possible way to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing Fine dude, yet I recommend you to avoid super large and nested files... In order to make it simplier to mantain and read, you can Split it on smaller components.